# Access to Sql Server via ODBC from C# : ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: c#, sql-server, odbc

I have a System DSN configured and test ok :

> Microsoft SQL Server Native Client Version 10.00.2531
>
> Data Source Name: xxx Data Source
>
> Description: xxx Server: SERVER\SHARE
>
> Use Integrated Security: Yes Database:
>
> yyy Language: (Default) Data
>
> Encryption: No Trust Server
>
> Certificate: No Multiple Active Result
>
> Sets(MARS): No Mirror Server:
>
> Translate Character Data: Yes Log Long
>
> Running Queries: No Log Driver
>
> Statistics: No Use Regional Settings:
>
> No Use ANSI Quoted Identifiers: Yes
>
> Use ANSI Null, Paddings and Warnings:
>
> Yes

I work on a windows 7 64 bits. The code in running in x86 mode.

In Excel, I can connect only to User DSN, the System DSN does not appear.
I tried also a use DSN, It works in excel but not in c#

I changed the permissions for the ODBC to everyone in regedit.

I use this connectionstring in the c# code : Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=yyy;Integrated Security=SSPI;

I have this error : ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Any idea ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I achieved to connect to the database without ODBC with that connection string:

```
 Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=xxx;Database=zzz;Trusted_Connection=yes;
```

Thanks !

Comment: You should edit your original post instead of adding an answer

Answer (score 3):

he initial problem posted here is most likely due to the fact that a 64bit ODBC Data Source has been created (using the ODBC Administrator via the Control Panel) and the app is only 32bit.

Put another way --

32bit apps require 32bit ODBC Drivers and 32bit DSNs (C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe)

64bit apps require 64bit ODBC Drivers and 64bit DSNs (C:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe)

32 and 64bit components CANNOT be interchanged here!!