# LogParser SQL Server driver windows 2012 x64

Tags: sql-server, odbc, windows-server-2012-r2, logparser

I have a logparser one liner which outputs in a SQL Server database.

I had a conversion problem between logparser timestamp and SQL Server `date(7)` types. I resolved this issue by specifying the driver

```
-driver "sql server native client 10.0"
```

Here is the whole oneliner :

```
LogParser "select to_date(to_timestamp('2015-03-13','yyyy-MM-dd')) AS REQ_DATE_DT, count(*) as REQ_REQUESTS_NU, 5 INTO MyTable from \\myServer\MyIISlog.log where time >= '12:00:00' and time <='14:59:59' " -i:IISW3C -o:SQL -createTable:OFF -server:MyServer\MyInstance -database:MyDB -username:myUser -password:MyPass -driver "sql server native client 10.0"
```

This command works well on my dev machine (windows 7 x64, SQL Server Management Studio installed). Now I want to run it from a script server (windows 2012r2 without ssms)

If I run the same command I have the following error :

> Task aborted.
>   Error connecting to ODBC Server
>   SQL State:     IM002
>   Native Error:  0
>   Error Message: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

If I change "SQL Server native client 10.0" to "SQL Server", I have the same error.

If I omit the -driver sql server part I have the usual convert error message

> SQL table column "REQ_DATE_DT" data type is not compatible with SELECT clause item "REQ_DATE_DT" (type TIMESTAMP)

So the db server is reachable and can be queried with the credentials I gave.

I installed the odbc drivers from microsoft msi and they appear in both ODBC Data Source Administrator x32 and x64.

I tried the odbc server 10 (SQL Server 2008 R2) and 11 (SQL Server 2012)

What am I missing?

**EDIT 1 :**

I tested installing several sql features with no success

- sqlncli, sqlCmdLnUtils and SharedManagementObjects (x64). I added the path to sqlcmd.exe to my $Path. The problem is still there, I can run sqlcmd and "Odbc Data Source" shows sql server 2008 driver (x86 and x64).
- I installed some more features with no success. Here is the list of the component I installed (x64) : SQL 2008 Command Line Utilities, Managment Objects, Native Client, Replication Management Objects, SQLXML 4.0 SP1, SQL Server System CLR Types, Powershell Extensions for SQL Server 2008. All these are x64 features.
- After installing the whole sql server stuff (including ssms, cli ...) I always encounter the same error

I'll try on other servers but I think it's a problem involving either only x64 sql native client or windows 2012r2 x64...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to tackle around the problem using the `-oConnString` LogParser option instead of `-driver -server -database ...` :

```
LogParser "select to_date(to_timestamp('2015-03-13','yyyy-MM-dd')) AS REQ_DATE_DT, count(*) as REQ_REQUESTS_NU, 5 INTO MyTable from \\myServer\MyIISlog.log where time >= '12:00:00' and time <='14:59:59' " -i:IISW3C -o:SQL -createTable:OFF -oConnString:"Driver={SQL server native client 10.0};server=MyServer;database=MyDB;uid=MyUser;pwd=MyUser;"
```

Due to this workaround, I think the original problem is a matter of ODBC x86 and x64.

Here are some questions that helped me :

- [Access to Sql Server via ODBC from C# : ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438788/access-to-sql-server-via-odbc-from-c-sharp-error-im002-microsoftodbc-driv?rq=1)
- https://serverfault.com/questions/144116/credentials-work-for-ssms-but-not-odbc-logparser-script

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to install the SQL Server Native Client (which is not the same as the ODBC driver), which can be found at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff658533.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396.

Comment: So, I uninstalled all sql features 2008/2008R2/2012 I had. I then installed sqlncli, sqlCmdLnUtils and SharedManagementObjects (x64). 
I added the path to sqlcmd.exe to my $Path.

The problem is still there, I can run sqlcmd and "Odbc Data Source" shows sql server 2008 driver (x86 and x64).

I'll try to install more features from SqlServer 2008 SP3.

Comment: I installed some more features with no success. Here is the list of the componeent I installed (x64) : SQL 2008 Command Line Utilities, Managment Objects, Native Client, Replication Management Objects, SQLXML 4.0 SP1, SQL Server System CLR Types, Powershell Extensions for SQL Server 2008. All these are x64 features. I wonder if LogParser (x86) can interact with the x64 native client. I think my next step will be to install a full ssms in the server...

Comment: After installing the whole sql server stuff (including ssms, cli ...) I always encounter the same error " [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified". I'll try on other servers but I think it's a problem involving windows 2012r2 x64...